# Eclipseで「スーパーインターフェースは、インタフェースでなければならない」という類のエラーメッセージが表示される

Tags: java

javaのEclipseで、「スーパーインタフェースはインタフェースでなければならない。」というエラーメッセージが出てくるのですか、どのように修正すれば、コンパイルできるようになりますか?
[image: エラーが、発生しているソースコードです]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　折角ご質問いただいたところ申し訳ありませんが、一般的に、エラーメッセージだけからその原因を詳細に特定するのは難しいです。可能であれば、関連しそうなソースコードをコピー＆ペーストで質問に [edit] ・追記いただけますでしょうか？　よろしくお願いします。

Comment: この辺の記事を参考に。[スーパーインターフェイスとは](http://www.kab-studio.biz/Programing/JavaA2Z/Word/00000504.html), [【Java入門】interfaceとimplementsの使い方を基礎の基礎から解説！](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/21542), [Java インターフェースデフォルト実装を継承して呼び出す方法](https://qiita.com/ota-meshi/items/7804a2414ae61e64dff0), [implementsキーワード](https://java-code.jp/108)

Answer (score 1):

質問の画像に含まれているコードには、

```
public class SampleImp implements Sample
```

と書かれています。

これは、「SampleImpというクラスは、Sampleというインタフェースを実装(implement)したものです」という意味です。

ここで「インタフェースでなければならない」というエラーが出るのだとしたら、Sampleがインタフェースではないのが原因だと考えられます（インターフェースを使っている(implementしている)のは最初に書いたコードのところだけですから）。

＝＝
　どのように修正するか判らないのは、質問者のクラスやインタフェースについての知識が足りないからです。
　それを解決するには、"初めてのJava"というような名前の本やMookを２，３冊、じっくりと読むと良いです。そうした本に問題が書かれていたら、それらを独力で解くと良い勉強になります。

kunifさんが紹介されているようなページで勉強するのも良いですが、できれば本やMookで勉強してください。
　なぜなら、本やMookのほうがJavaに関する事項を網羅的に書いているからです。

がんばってください！

Answer (score 1):

`Sample.java` を開き、次のようにインタフェースとして定義してください。

```java
package chaper1.chapter2;

public interface Sample {
}
```

---

Eclipseでは、インタフェースとして定義した場合、アイコンの右肩に `I` のマークが付きます。
が、質問文中の画像ではそうなっていません。
おそらく `interface` でなく `class` になっていると思われます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

コード全文を見れないので推測でお答えしますが、
3行目"implements"を"extends"へ書き換えてください。

質問者様は　インターフェースの実装　と　クラスの継承　がごっちゃになっていると思われます。
原因を理解するためには
・インターフェースとは何か
・インターフェースの実装
・クラスとは何か
・クラスの継承
あたりを検索してみるのが良いかと思います。